# Grand-parents tag should be grandparents without a hyphen

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

While I'm on a tagging kick, I noticed that Beofett's retagging of [grand-parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-parents) that it is misspelled.  In English, it is not commonly spelled with either a hyphen or a space.  I propose we create [grandparents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grandparents) and make [grand-parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-parents) a synonym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's misspelled with the hyphen then we don't need to vote about it. I think you can just fix it. And it's a good idea to have the hyphened version as a synonym so it won't reappear.